# Constructing group extensions in GAP.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, group-extensions

I have the following general question: Given two finite groups $N$ and $H$, how can we find, using GAP, all the groups $G$ (up to an isomorphism, of course) such that 
$$1 \rightarrow N \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1$$ is a short exact sequence? For splitting sequences, I know how to solve the problem (computing semidirect products), but I have no idea how to construct non-splitting sequences.

Comment: why is finite in parentheses? are they finite or not? if they are, say it very explicitly

Comment: [This](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap46.html#X877AAB887D4507E3) is the closest I could find in the GAP manual.

Comment: Unfortunately, the method for Pc groups is working only if $N$ is Abelian... and I want to construct examples in the general case.

Comment: There is code in the development version that will make it into GAP 4.11 (function `TwoCohomologyGeneric`) for doing exactly this (for elementary abelian $N$). At this point you would have to install the development version from github, it is not really possible to extract the code for an older release. If you have a single example let me know and I can run the code for you.

Comment: I'm interested in a case when $N$ is not abelian...

Comment: If $N$ is not abelian, you can split it into elementary layers. Solvable ones will come from cohomology, non-solvable ones basically mean you have a larger nonsolvable factor group with a nice structure as subgroup of the automorphism group of the layer.

Comment: @Mircea Do you have a particular example of $N$ and $H$ in mind?

Comment: I have in mind the case: $N$ is solvable and $H$ is a p-group with $p\nmid |N|$.

Comment: @ahulpke So you could, say, use this to construct the extensions with kernel SmallGroup(32,17) and quotient group $\mathbb{Z}_8^2$ (two copies of the cyclic group of order 8)?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy  Yes. You would find a characteristic series for the normal subgroup and iteratively form extensions using cohomology.

Answer (score 5):

Your comments indicate that you are interested in a case of $\gcd(|N|,|H|)=1$. In this situation (due to the Schur/Zassenhaus theorem) any extension is a semidirect product.
You can classify such extensions by computing the `AutomorphismGroup` of $N$ and computing (classes of) homomorphisms from $H$ to $\mbox{Aut}(N)$: E.g.

```
gap> N:=AbelianGroup([5,5,5]);
<pc group of size 125 with 3 generators>
gap> H:=SymmetricGroup(4);;
gap> au:=AutomorphismGroup(N);
<group with 4 generators>
gap> homs:=AllHomomorphismClasses(H,au);
[ [ (1,3,2), (3,4) ] -> [ [ f1, f2, f3 ] -> [ f1, f2, f3 ],
      [ f1, f2, f3 ] -> [ f1, f2, f3 ] ], [...]o
gap> ext:=List(homs,x->SemidirectProduct(H,x,N));
[ <pc group of size 3000 with 7 generators>,
  <pc group of size 3000 with 7 generators>,
  <pc group of size 3000 with 7 generators>,
  <pc group of size 3000 with 7 generators>,
  <pc group of size 3000 with 7 generators>,
  <pc group of size 3000 with 7 generators>,
  <pc group of size 3000 with 7 generators>,
  <pc group of size 3000 with 7 generators> ]
gap> List(ext,x->Length(ConjugacyClasses(x))); # show they are non-isomorphic
[ 625, 253, 325, 265, 38, 165, 26, 105 ]
```